# Doctrine inheritance for entities common fields

Tags: php, inheritance, doctrine-orm, zend-framework3, zf3

I'm using Zend Framework 3 and Doctrine ORM for my web project.

I have several modules in my application (`User`, `Stock`, `Sales`) and some entity models on each Module:

- `User` module entities: `User`, `Account`, etc..
- `Stock` module entities: `SKU`, `StockLevel`, etc..
- `Sales` module entities: `Invoice`, `PaymentMethod`, etc..

By default all entities has common fields, things like:

- `creationDateTime`: Date/time of creation
- `creationUser`: User who create the entity
- `lastChangeDateTime`: Date/time of last entity change
- `lastChangeUser`: User who last changed the entity

I don't want to put those fields or every entity, but rather create a project base class that will extend all of my entities. I need to have common methods that will work on all entities, ie:

```
  /**
   * Update the last change fields
   * @param string $user User that is updating 
   */
  public void updateLastChange($user)
  {
      $this->lastChageDataTime = \Datetime();
      $this->lastChangeUser = $user;
  }
```

As I can see [from the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html), it seens that I need to use the single table inheritance, but I can't figure out exactly how. Questions:

**a)** By using single table inheritance, will Doctrine create a base table in database for these fields or will join the base and the entity fields for every entity table, or in other words, will I have just the entity table or this inheritance will create a database table for the base fields also ?

**b)** Where should I put my base entity so that it can be inherited for all entities on different module ?

I would appreciate it someone could put some example/links on how to do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For what you want to do single table inheritance is not what you need.

There are 2 options:

### 1)  MappedSuperClass (almost straight from the documentation)

You make a `MappedSuperClass` (documentation can be found in chapter **[6.1: Mapped Superclasses](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses)**) and you add those common fields in that base class. Then you extend all the classes that need those fields from your base (mapped super) class.

```
/** 
 * @MappedSuperclass 
 */
class MappedSuperclassBase
{
    /** @Column(type="datetime") */
    protected $creationDateTime;

    /** 
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\User") 
     * @JoinColumn(name="created_by", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $creationUser;

    /** @Column(type="datetime") */
    protected $lastChangeDateTime;

    /** 
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\User") 
     * @JoinColumn(name="updated_by", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $lastChangeUser;

    // ... more fields and methods
}

/** 
 * @Entity 
 */
class EntitySubClass extends MappedSuperclassBase
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") */
    private $id;

    // ... more fields and methods
}
```

### 2) You use a Trait

You make a trait (or several separate traits for each field/association) that you use inside all the classes which need to have those common fields.

```
trait BaseTrait
{
    /** @Column(type="datetime") */
    protected $creationDateTime;

    /** 
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\User") 
     * @JoinColumn(name="created_by", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $creationUser;

    /** @Column(type="datetime") */
    protected $lastChangeDateTime;

    /** 
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\User") 
     * @JoinColumn(name="updated_by", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $lastChangeUser ;

    // ... more fields and methods
}

/** 
 * @Entity 
 */
class EntitySubClass
{
    use BaseTrait;

    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") */
    private $id;

    // ... more fields and methods
}
```

### Answers to your questions:

**a)** In the docs you can read:

> Single Table Inheritance is an inheritance mapping strategy where all classes of a hierarchy are mapped to a single database table. In order to distinguish which row represents which type in the hierarchy a so-called discriminator column is used.

It would mean that all those entities would share a common table, this absolutely not what you want. It will probably become a huge table (a row for each entity) slowing down your queries. On top of this there will also be columns in the table for **all not commonly shared fields** and those columns would be empty (`null`) for the entities that don't have those fields. It also means those not shared fields cannot have a `null` constraint. Again straight from the documentation:

> For Single-Table-Inheritance to work in scenarios where you are using either a legacy database schema or a self-written database schema you have to make sure that all columns that are not in the root entity but in any of the different sub-entities has to allows null values. Columns that have NOT NULL constraints have to be on the root entity of the single-table inheritance hierarchy.

Such inheritance is only necessary for entities that are similar to a huge extend and is not suitable for the examples you are talking about in your question.

**b)** You can just add the base entity (so the `MappedSuperClass`) in a common model (like your `Application` folder).

Comment: I would recommend the trait method. You can then implement general listeners, that will set these fields automatically. Have a look at - https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors - they did most of the job for you J

Comment: `trait` is working perfectly, including with `orm:generate:entities`. Thanks a lot. Jan, the subscriber stuff is a plus.