# Symfony form common fields inheritance/composition

Tags: php, forms, symfony, inheritance, composition

I have 2 entities `A` and `B` that share common fields, I used a `trait` to setup those common fields based on ([Doctrine inheritance for entities common fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40847451/doctrine-inheritance-for-entities-common-fields)) because I don't want to use a `MappedSuperClass`.

Setting up a restful post route for entity `B`, I instantiate a `FormBType` which `data_class` maps to `B::class`, that extends `FormCType` (contains common fields and '`data_class`' maps to nothing).

I tried to use the inherit_data approach with https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/inherit_data_option.html but I don't want that extra key/nested layer in my form (I want a flattened one).

My problem is that validation for the common fields which are in the trait using Assert aren't taken into account and form passes `validation` with empty strings.

```
class B {
use CTrait;
}


//trait that has the common fields with ORM mapping and Assert
trait CTrait {
/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
*/
private $id;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string")
* @ORM\Assert\Length(min="2")
*/
private $name;
}


//Common fields formType
class CType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
    }
}

//Form using the common fields formType
class BType extends CType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => B::class,
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further checking on [Length](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Length.html) I realized empty strings are considered valid values and it was still passing through validation using `name: ""` even though I had `Assert\Length(min=2)`, after adding [NotBlank](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotBlank.html) the validation worked.